# How to call a stored procedure with parameters in powerbuilder12

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, powerbuilder

I'm using sybase powerbilder12 IDE and mySQL.

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
 DELIMITER //
  CREATE PROCEDURE CRTempTable(IN loc_code CHAR(6))
   BEGIN
    create temporary table mstparameter (select * from    mstparameter_consolidate where location_code = 'loc_code');
  END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm calling it in the powerbuilder12 like this:

```
DECLARE TempTBCRCall PROCEDURE FOR TempTableCR  
         location_code = :gs_location_code_mstparameter  ;
execute TempTBCRCall;
```

It gives me the error :

> Stored procedure execution failure1054  SQLSTATE = S0022
>
> [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.25a]Unknown column
>   'location_code' in 'field list'...  Error Code 0

but `location_code` is there in my `mstparameter_consolidate` table.

If I set to enter the `location_code` manually it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example that works, I hope it helps you.

```
DECLARE pb_acceso_usuario PROCEDURE FOR SP_ACCESO_VALIDA_DATOS_USUARIO (:gs_cod_usuario,:ls_password);
execute pb_acceso_usuario;

if SQLCA.sqlcode = 0 then
   FETCH pb_acceso_usuario INTO :ln_count,:gs_des_usuario,:ls_estado;
   CLOSE pb_acceso_usuario; 
end if
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me to find out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try putting "table-name." in front of the column-name.